# How do I merge the answers I gave with my unregistered account with the answers I gave using the account I created later?

Tags: support, answers, unregistered-users

I have answered a question ([How to detect session timeout in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845452)); I then registered an account with my OpenID, but the answer has not been assigned to my current account.
What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both accounts shared the same details, I went ahead and merged them. For future reference, see [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 1):

Flag the question for a mod and explain the situation, they can merge it to your account.